# Enforcing a local and remote port with the same socket at the same time

Tags: c, sockets, networking, port

I am currently working on getting the publicly available inputpipe program to work with a Packet Forwarder for a custom network.

This forwarder takes a configuration file during startup, and forwards specified ports through the network.

My problem right now is the following:

When i run the inputpipe client(the PC that the USB device is attached to) and the server(the PC where the USB device gets emulated) i can specify the port, that the server will listen upon. (The server then bind() s and listen() s on that specific port).

My problem right now is that the client will create the socket() and then connect() to the server by means of IP adress and remote port. During this process, the clients' OS will assign a random port number to the socket through which it connects.

Since I need to specify the outgoing port to the forwarder before actually running the server, this makes it impossible. I tried bind() ing the socket before connect() ing but this only seems to work when target and source machine are the same (when connecting via localhost) and doesn't work when using actual separate machines.

Long story short: Is there a way to specify a remote port as well as a local port for a socket?

edit: My code that doesnt work for whatever reason:

```
  struct sockaddr_in in_addr;

  /* Struct for the bind call
  */

  struct sockaddr_in out_addr;

  /*
  */ 


  struct hostent* host;
  int fd;
  int opt = 1;

  /* Allocate the new server object */
  self = malloc(sizeof(struct server));
  assert(self != NULL);
  memset(self, 0, sizeof(struct server));

  /* Parse the host:port string */
  self->host = strdup(host_and_port);
  self->port = IPIPE_DEFAULT_PORT;
  p = strchr(self->host, ':');
  if (p) {
    *p = '\0';
    self->port = atoi(p+1);
  }

  /* New socket */
  fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("socket");
    server_delete(self);
    return NULL;
  }
 /* Bind the socket to remote port +1 */
  memset(&out_addr, 0, sizeof(out_addr));
  out_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  out_addr.sin_port = htons(self->port+1);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &(out_addr.sin_addr));

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&out_addr, sizeof out_addr)) {
    perror("Binding failed");
    close(fd);
    server_delete(self);
    return NULL;
  } 

  /* Connect the socket to our parsed address */
  host = gethostbyname(self->host);
  if (!host) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unknown host '%s'\n", self->host);
    close(fd);
    server_delete(self);
    return NULL;
  }
  memset(&in_addr, 0, sizeof(in_addr));
  in_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  memcpy(&in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, host->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr));
  in_addr.sin_port = htons(self->port);

  if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*) &in_addr, sizeof(in_addr))) {
    perror("Connecting to inputpipe-server");
    close(fd);
    server_delete(self);
    return NULL;
  }
```

Comment: Please show the code of what you tried. The provided information is not enough to help you with your problem.

Comment: Can you explain WHY you need socket source port fixed?

Comment: @ user315052 It is hard to post only the necessary codebits so I would like to point you to the inputpipe program http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/inputpipe/src/ basically what I need is the port opened by the client @ client.c @ in the function "static struct server* server_new(const char *host_and_port)" to not only connect to a specific remote port, but also to a specific local port.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov as I said, I am using a Packetforwarder to forward standard ethernet packets through a custom network. This Packetforwarder takes a configuration file at startup which tells it which local port to sniff the packets from and forward them through the network. Since the local port will be random for the client if I don't bind it (which cannot be done at the same time as connect) this effectively renders my setup useless because I need to run the packetforwarder before the inputpipe.

Comment: @user315052 bind() can most certainly be used together with connect() to accomplish what you want, though your code here binds to "127.0.0.1", which will naturally not work when connecting to a remote machine.  One other issue is if something else uses that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand your reasoning for needing source port fixed, but anyway ...

You are confusing `bind(2)` and `listen(2)`. It's the `listen(2)` system call that is mutually exclusive with `connect(2)`. `bind(2)` just fixes "local name", i.e. source port number for the socket.

#### Edit 0:

Ah, the code ...

You are binding to `127.0.0.1` - you cannot connect from here to anything non-local, thus the error. Use `INADDR_ANY` or your real routable address instead.

Comment: Believe me, I read up on listen and bind since it took me some time to arrive at where I am now. As i mentioned above, even if, officially, they are not mutually exclusive, the code posted above doesn't work as whoever gets called second just fails. As for needing source port fixed, as I said, my forwarder is sniffing a preconfigured port for ethernet packets to forward them. If you don't bind the socket, the OS assigns a random port from which the packets are sent, making it impossible to capture them with the forwarder.

Comment: And no, `select` is not broken ... :)

Comment: Just trying to understand for myself here, the reason this doesnt work is that 127.0.0.1 "resides" on the loopback interface while the address I am connecting to is resolved via the eth0 or whatever interface?

Comment: If you send a packet out your eth0 interface to another machine, and the packet has a source address of 127.0.0.1, how is the other machine going to respond? It can't; that's why the kernel refuses to send such a packet as requested by your bind and connect

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, this may help

```
fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// Local
memset(&sa_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sa_loc.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa_loc.sin_port = htons(LOCAL_RANDOM_PORT); /// PUT the port here which you want to open
sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS);

ret = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_loc, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
assert(ret != -1);

// Remote
memset(&sa_dst, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
sa_dst.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa_dst.sin_port = htons(80);
sa_dst.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("64.233.163.104"); // google :)

ret = connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_dst, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
assert(ret != -1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with this is after binding the port, I cannot connect() it to the server anymore since connect() and bind() cannot be used in conjunction

Comment: Yes, I tried. The connect() call throws an invalid argument error if I use bind() on the same socket before. If I comment out the bind() command everything runs fine. - Same the other way around, if I connect first bind will not work. I recall reading somewhere that you cannot use both on the same socket.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` in the bind call here is wrong, it should be `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof(sa_loc)`